# How to get keyboard height on a web app

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, progressive-web-apps

This is for a web app, targeting any mobile browser but mainly Chrome and Safari for iOS10.
The browser opens the built-in keyboard when the user clicks on any input, which is fine, but I am trying to resize/relocate the items more relevant to the user at that point in time.

Is there anyway to calculate the height of the keyboard so that I can adjust items accordingly? Generic solution would be better, as inputs may open different types of keyboard (text, numeric...) but hard coding options are also a valid response at this stage.

I have tested around *window.screen*, *window.innerHeight* and so on to no avail...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: Thanks Alex for the suggestion but, unless I am missing something, media queries are useful to define different layouts for different viewports, but the viewport does not change when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: I tried `@media all and (max-height: 700px)`, which triggered when opening the soft keyboard. Tested on Chrome browser on a Samsung S6, Android 6.0.1. You may also have success with `window.onresize`. Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3yn2yz1/6/) with your phone.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your new suggestion. Your fiddle does recalculate the height of the window when the keyboard is displayed. The media management is not required though - at least for my case, as all I needed is the javascript logic to get the old and new size. I believe the window.onresize was the trigger I was missing in my own scenario. You did answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: Apart from media queries you are also able to use the viewport height (vh). Neither media queries, vh or window.onresize work on iOS.

http://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/full/ggLKvx/

Comment: It's tricky, because for certain cases it's impossible to get the full height of the keyboard. On android you can calculate the keyboard size by getting the window.innerHeight after the keyboard is displayed. However some keyboards have an additional widget bar on top which doesn't affect the viewport size so you can't calculate it. For example Samsung Keyboard 5.2.40.0 has this additional bar which includes password/payment/address manager, when the input type is `text`, `url` or `email`

Answer (score 3):

There is a web standards to tackle this issue.

The [Visual Viewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API), which also allows to listen to the [`resize` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport/resize_event).

> The visual viewport is the visual portion of a screen excluding on-screen keyboards, areas outside of a pinch-zoom area, or any other on-screen artifact that doesn't scale with the dimensions of a page.

```js
visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const h = event.target.height
  …
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you. It's also well-standardized, unlike the VirtualKeyboard API.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Note:*** The credit of this answer fully goes to the user [Alex k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321016/alex-k). However his solution has already been accepted by OP within
>   *comments section and I guess these should have to be in answer section*
>   *as this is a very useful question.*

To solve the problem, try [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) like this:

```js
var d = document.getElementById('d');

checkDimensions();

window.onresize = checkDimensions;

function checkDimensions(prevHeight) {
  d.innerHTML = 'Window dimensions: ' + window.innerWidth + ' x ' + window.innerHeight;
}
```

```css
.media-query-test {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

@media all and (max-height: 700px) {
  .media-query-test {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />

<div id="d">
</div>

<div class="media-query-test">
  Height is less than 700px!
</div>
```

And here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3yn2yz1/6/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321016/alex-k) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684804/how-to-get-keyboard-height-on-a-web-app/74997968#comment70568763_41684804):

> I tried @media all and (max-height: 700px), which triggered when
> opening the soft keyboard. Tested on Chrome browser on a Samsung S6,
> Android 6.0.1. You may also have success with window.onresize